# Cache clear using clearApplicationUserData() method in Android

Tags: android, caching

I am using `clearApplicationUserData()` to clear the application cache. Once it runs close the activity suddenly. Not calls `onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy()` of the Activity. Pls can someone explain me how this method works?